# posts_request, posts_results, and the_posts one time run

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, hook

In WordPress, I am performing on-site searches with both regular site search and AJAX. After these searches, I want to retrieve the query made through hooks, as well as data such as found posts and post type. I have used the hooks posts_request, posts_results, and the_posts. However, in on-site searches made through AJAX, it works once, while in regular on-site searches, it works twice. Can you help me with this? Thank you in advance.

```
class My_Custom_Class {
    private static $isExecuted = false;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('posts_results', array($this, 'my_custom_posts_results'), 10, 2);
    }

    public function my_custom_posts_results($posts, $query) {
        if (!self::$isExecuted) {
            if ($query->is_search()) {
                if ($query->found_posts > 0) {
                    // Actions to be performed
                    // ...
                }
                self::$isExecuted = true;
            }
        }

        return $posts;
    }
}

$my_custom_instance = new My_Custom_Class();
```